# How to automate web app upload to cumlocity using the azure devOps

Tags: cumulocity

We have developed an web application using the angular 6 and uploading it manually using the adamos --> "Add application" option in administration Page.

We want to automate the process of building & deploying the application to the adamos.

Currently we are using Azure devOps, for building the angular App and creating a dist folder. Now how do i automate the process of uploading my web app in adamos.

Please let me know, any possibility is there now?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing the Azure devOps you usually use the CLI provided by Cumulocity (via npm) for build & deploy. That is usually also the approach for other CI like Jenkins.

The deploy process itself is just containing REST calls (like the UI also does). So that part you could do also easily without the CLI tool.